# Unable to Cast a Matlab COM object in C#

Tags: c#, matlab, com

Hello everyone I'm trying to control Matlab from a C# application, so I went for the COM server solution however I can't make it work.

First, I registered my Matlab as COM server using `comserver('register','User','all')` in the Matlab Command Window. I then referenced this server in my C# project.

After that I implemented simple C# code to access a Matlab function that I wrote :

```
        // Create the MATLAB instance 
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); // Where the code returns an error

        // Change to the directory where the function is located 
        matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\jar\Downloads\");

        // Define the output 
        object result = null;

        // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
        matlab.Feval("traj2D_image",1, out result,
                                        ParametresBalayage.NomFichier,
                                        ParametresBalayage.LongueurBalayage,
                                        ParametresBalayage.NbBalayage,
                                        ParametresBalayage.PasBalayage,
                                        ParametresBalayage.DecalageBalayage,
                                        ParametresBalayage.DecalageStries,
                                        ParametresBalayage.Vitesse,
                                        sens);

        // Display result 
        object[] res = result as object[];
```

But I get this error when I try to create the MATLAB instance :

```
System.InvalidCastException : 'Unable to cast a COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' into interface type 'MLApp.MLApp'. This operation failed, because calling QueryInterface on the COM component for the interface with the IID '{669CEC93-6E22-11CF-A4D6-00A024583C19}' has failed because of the following error : Unspecified error (HRESULT Exception : 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).'
```

This is weird because the Matlab instance is created, a new Matlab Command Window opens, but the code doesn't go further and stops.

Does anyone know why I have this problem? Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT : trying another method**

I followed step by step the MathWorks' instructions but it still gives me the same error when creating the `MLApp` instance so I tried to explore other options such as manually [register, unregister, or query MATLAB COM server](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/comserver.html) but nothing changed. I still want the first option to work but I went to see other .NET languages to see how [they were implementing that](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/creating-the-matlab-server.html).

So I'm trying another method that [I found in VB.NET](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-a-matlab-function-from-visual-basic-net-client.html) and that works in an excel VBA module :
Type mlType;
Object matlab;

```
        mlType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Matlab.Application");
        matlab = Activator.CreateInstance(mlType);

        Console.WriteLine(matlab.???("surf(peaks)")); // what do i have to put here?
```

This creates an instance of MAtlab without returning any error however in VB.NET there is an `Execute` class in objects that I don't have here so I tried `matlab.Equals("surf(peaks)")` (which is obviously not the right method) but I don't know what to put to get the instance to do what I want.

Comment: I think the VB.NET code magically works because VB.NET is by default loosely typed and allows calling methods on types even if they are unknown at compile time. In order to mimick this behavior, I'd try to type the matlab object as dynamic, and then to call Execute on it.   Sure you won't get intellisense, but the compiler won't complain.
In short:

dynamic matlab = Activator.CreateInstance(mlType);
matlab.Execute("surf(peaks)");

Comment: @odalet that works, but indeed it seems like it could be unstable. I'll keep searching in that direction though! Thank you!

Comment: Well, it will be as unstable as what you'd have with the VB.NET Code, that is... possibly unstable due to the nature of how methods are resolved at runtime. Indeed, such code must be really tested because the compiler won't help you detect bad invocations! I wish I could help you with a strongly-typed solution, but I do not have an installation of Matlab and hence cannot reproduce your issue with the COM interop. If you happen to succeed in your tests, please say so here, I'll convert my comment into an answer explaining how the VB.NET syntax can be "translated" to C#.

Comment: Did you try dynamic ?  dynamic matlab = Activator.CreateInstance(mlType); than matlib.surf(peaks)

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan yes I did for the other method, I didn't for the first one though, I'll try that.

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan it doesn't work for the first method